# Add a link in customer's email to create an event based on order in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications

In Woocommerce, I am trying to edit the email template for customer invoice email and I don't know how to write the right code to show the product name and time. How this can be done?

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my code *(added to function.php file)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_after_order_table', 'add_content_specific_email', 20, 4 );

function add_content_specific_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    if ( $email->id == 'customer_invoice' ) {
        echo '<a href="http://www.google.com/calendar/event?action=TEMPLATE&text=[LocalRunners]$item_name"><h2 class="email-upsell-title"> Add to my calendar</h2></a>';
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by product time? Also remember that an order can have many items, so different product names…

Comment: because my site want to provide local tour. Usually client will book a date for tour. so I want let customer to add to calendar according the date to remind them. And usually they will only book one product in an order.

Comment: Regarding time, are you referring any custom meta field here?

Comment: maybe yes......, because I am not professional in coding....Just trying to figure it out.Thank you :)